# What should I do if the dependency injection exception occurs when the SprintBoot project is running?

Tags: java

Description:

Field am in wow.service.AdminServiceImpl required a bean of type 'wow.mapper.AdminMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'wow.mapper.AdminMapper' in your configuration.

```
@Mapper
public interface AdminMapper {

    @Select("select user_count from t_usercount")
    Integer getUserCount();
    
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT)
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {

    @Autowired
    private AdminMapper am;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public BackJSON getUserCount() {
        BackJSON json = new BackJSON(200);
        String count = "{\"count\":"+am.getUserCount()+"}";
        json.setData(JSONObject.parse(count));
        return json;
    }

}
```

Field am in wow.service.AdminServiceImpl required a bean of type 'wow.mapper.AdminMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: Change `@Mapper` to `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. If the mapper interface is within spring's component scan, the generated mapper will then be injectable.

Comment: There is no componentModel attribute

Comment: `@Mapper` is `org.mapstruct.Mapper`, yes? If so: [there is a `componentModel` field](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html#componentModel()).